# How can i change mediapath by src in each track of Plyr audio playlist?

Tags: javascript

i found this playlist Plyr hier: http://jsfiddle.net/CAT999/1oL6w5jm/23/
But i don't want get audio from mediaPath = 'https://archive.org/download/mythium/'

```
var index = 0,
            playing = false,
            mediaPath = 'https://archive.org/download/mythium/',
            extension = '',
            tracks = [{
                "track": 1,
                "name": "All This Is - Joe L.'s Studio",
                "duration": "2:46",
                "file": "JLS_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 2,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Broadwing Studio (Final Mix)",
                "duration": "8:30",
                "file": "BS_TF"
            }
```

I want to change mediaPath by  src in each track , example

```
           "track": 1,

            "name": "All This Is - Joe L.'s Studio",

            "src": "https://...mp3",

            "duration": "2:46",

            "file": "JLS_ATI"
```

How can i edit it?

Thank you so much

Change the way to get the audio file link